# How to handle objects with circular reference in Avro

Tags: java, serialization, avro

I have the following code to serialize an object into Avro.

```
List childrenList = new ArrayList ();
RootNode root = new RootNode();
root.setChildrenList(childrenList);

ChildNode child1 = new ChildNode();
child1.setParent(root);
childrenList.add(child1);

ChildNode child2 = new ChildNode();
child2.setParent(root);
childrenList.add(child2);

Schema schema = ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(root.getClass());
DatumWriter datumWriter = new ReflectDatumWriter (root.getClass());
DataFileWriter fileWriter = new DataFileWriter (datumWriter);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
fileWriter.create(schema, baos);
fileWriter.append(root);
```

But this goes into an infinite loop because of circular reference between root and children.

Ultimately, Apache Avro fails with a stackoverflow error.

I have searched a lot everywhere but there does not seem to be any option to fix this.

Does anyone know how to make Avro handle circular references?

Update: I know of two other serializer frameworks - Gson and Jackson and only Jackson handles circular references very well. So I am doubtful if Avro would have a solution for this since it does not look to be a commonly occurring case?

Answer (score 0):

Circular references request was done in [AVRO-695](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-695) and the fix has been committed with [AVRO-1692](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1692)

A test for the same can be found at [TestCircularReferences.java](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/trunk/lang/java/avro/src/test/java/org/apache/avro/TestCircularReferences.java)

Note that circular references in schema are now supported in Hive as well with [HIVE-7653](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7653)